# First order ODE with random force

Tags: differential-equations, random

I need to solve using first order Euler method some simple equation
$ \frac{dc}{dt} +3 c = f(t) $

where $f(t)$ is random delta-correlated force: $<f(t_1)f(t_2)>=2A \delta(t_1-t_2)$

Searching for similar problems I found that:

- I need to use first order Euler method
- $A$ should be a random variable with zero mean and 1 distribution
- I should divide $A$ by $\sqrt dt$ in actual calculation (see this discussion for details https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11363/how-to-include-random-force-in-the-simulation-classical-molecular-dynamics)

My code:

```
 MyEuler[start_, end_, initialvalue_, nrOfsteps_] :=
    Module[{a = start, b = end, j, m = nrOfsteps}, h = (b - a)/m; 
    T = Table[a + (j - 1) h, {j, 1, m + 1}];
    rnd = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
    Y = Table[initialvalue, {j, 1, m + 1}];
    For[j = 1, j <= m, j++, 
    Y[[j + 1]] = Y[[j]] + h f[T[[j]], Y[[j]]]] + (2 rnd)/Sqrt[h];
    Transpose@{T, Y}]
    f[t_, x_] = -3 x;(*rhs of ODE without thermal noise*)
    pts = MyEuler[0.0, 3.0, 10.0, 20];
    ListLinePlot[pts, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, Frame -> True]
```

But the results is just decaying amplitude without any random force indications in it. How should I modify this code to get correct answer? Namely $c(t)$ should relax not  to zero value but to some level given by a random force amplitude I believe.

Comment: Not sure about the meaning of $<f(t_1)f(t_2)>=2A \delta(t_1-t_2)$ but 1. `+ (2 rnd)/Sqrt[h]` should be inside `For`; 2. `rnd = ` should probably be `rnd := `

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. Puting random part inside of for helps, but resulting function is random, but not what I expect - just random walks around 0 value and not relaxing into some value

Comment: Have a look at `ItoProcess` in order to get a solution which might be a useful guide to your approach.

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process?  If so, there's a builtin `OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess` function.  Otherwise, as @b.gatessucks says, `ItoProcess` can handle more general stochastic differential equations.

Comment: After a second look, I believe it should be `rnd h` i.e. `rnd/Sqrt[h] h` rather than `rnd/Sqrt[h]`.

Comment: OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess or ItoProcess are build-in function but I want to code simple Random Euler solver myself to tinker it later for additional things, like time dependence of noise amplitude etc.

Comment: If I understand the question right, you want to solve the ode `c'[t]+3 c[t]==2 A DiracDelta[t-t1]`? To use Euler etc. is your solution idea and not a requirement? If so, Mathematica is able to solve the problem `c'[t]+3 c[t]==DiracDelta[t-t1]` analytically. The solution is greensfunction which can be used to describe the general solution of your ode...

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account the comments made xzczd and rewriting your code to both simplify it and make more robust, I come up with this.

```
myEuler[func_, start_, end_, initialvalue_, nrOfsteps_] :=
  Module[{h, T, rnd, Y, j, m = nrOfsteps + 1},
    rnd := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
    h = (end - start)/nrOfsteps;
    T = start + h (Range[m] - 1);
    Y = ConstantArray[initialvalue, m];
    For[j = 1, j < m, j++,
      Y[[j + 1]] = Y[[j]] + h (func[T[[j]], Y[[j]]] + (2 rnd)/Sqrt[h])];
    Transpose[{T, Y}]]

f[t_, x_] := -3 x + t

SeedRandom[42]
pts = myEuler[f, 0.0, 3.0, 10.0, 50];
ListLinePlot[pts,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> Red,
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Here is a functional programming solution that greatly simplifies the function `myEuler`. It will produce exactly same result as the implementation using `For`. It may be a little harder to understand, but it is worth studying because it is very concise and much more efficient than any code building arrays and processing them with `For`.

```
myEuler[func_, start_, end_, initialvalue_, nrOfsteps_] :=
  Module[{rnd, h},
    rnd := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]];
    h = (end - start)/nrOfsteps;
    FoldPairList[
      {{#2, #1}, #1 + h (func[#2, #1] + (2 rnd)/Sqrt[h])} &, 
      initialvalue, 
      start + h Range[0, nrOfsteps]]]
```

Comment: this class of problem needs specialized methods - not my area of expertise for sure, but I do know enough that comments in the question itself are on the mark (Ito process, Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process).

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=99&ob=title&o=ASC&p=2&disp=list&v=98 for example (I am not affiliated with Wolfram or Pavlyk)

Comment: @Paul_A. I am not addressing the underlying issue of whether the OP can hope to get reasonable results by employing Euler's method. I am only trying to address the programming issues his question raises.

Comment: I missed that, my apologies. I read many of your polished and detailed MMA programming solutions - am an admirer of yours in that regard.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but why f[t_, x_] := -3 x + t and not just  f[x]=-3x? Also from previous comments I'm still not sure how noise should be included: as h (2 rnd)/Sqrt[h] or h (2 rnd)/Sqrt[h])

Comment: @denkorw. The 1st argument to `myEuler` can be any function of two variables. For testing purposes, I wanted it to be a function in which both variables were actually used. You can and maybe should try it with `f`defined as `f[t_, x_] := 3 x` or you can modify `myEuler` to so that `func` is a function of one variable, but is not good practice to pass a function of one variable into a function that expects a function of two variables as an argument.